# voip integration in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, voip, sip, telephony

I have an asp.net web page with a "dial" button; when the user presses the button, it connects the user to the PTSN network to make a phone call. This is for outbound calling only so there's no need to worry about incoming calls.

I'm thinking of using a webphone and finding a VOIP wholesale provider. Ideally, I'd like the server that's hosting the web app to not be involved in this process (ie. the webphone connects directly to the VOIP provider).

What are some of the pitfalls to avoid?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few Flash based softphones around you could use. I'd recommend taking a look at [Phono](http://www.phono.com/) from [Tropo](http://tropo.com/). It's designed for initiating calls via javascript in the browser. I think it does or will use HTML5 where available but falls back to Flash for some parts.

Comment: ok, it looks really interesting. I hope it can connect with any VOIP provider. I'm still searching to see which codec it uses. How is the ilbc codec?

Comment: I don't know which codec it uses between the browser and the Tropo servers. I suspect it's a proprietary Flash one and unlikely to be ilbc. Tropo will forward the call to any SIP URI so in that sense you can connect to any SIP provider you want.

Answer (score -1):

One pitfall: WHat you describe is not a web page, it is a local application the user has to install ON HIS COMPUTER. Mileage may wary.

ASP.NET is not running on the users side (beginner mistake). It is a server side technology - the user basicall gets normal HTML, Javascript... which has NO higher programming capabilities and no voip capabilities. Lize a pizza delivery - asp.net is the top oven, but the user gets a normal pizza. Point.

So, your pitfall is that you need to make a web call out of a HTML page (no asp.net involved, no .net involved) and this is not possible without the user installing software on his computer.

SOmething like FLASH may work, or silverlight. But I expect some rights issues (especially: connect to ANOTHER server, not the server hthe flash / silverlight plug in was loaded from) which require configuration / epriviledge elevation, i.e. no normal users again.

Comment: Thanks. I'm well aware of the difference you're mentioning; I wanted to provide context in case it'd be helpful. I've looked at several webphones and VOIP providers and I was wondering if you, according to your experience, there were some holes to avoid.

Comment: Only that it i a freaking pain;) It is ok if wyou live in your own world (company), but the moment you go out it is wild.